# How to disable formatting

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor

Everytime I copy something, Wordpress will format the content like it was in that text. For example if I copy a link from Wikipedia, Wordpress will format that word to be bold, blue and with underline. This is tilting me so hard.

I have tried the following from [Disable TinyMCE autoformatting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145420/disable-tinymce-autoformatting) and I didn't noticed anything

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

I have also tried this plugin, it doesn't work and it generates errors
https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/ps-disable-auto-formatting

How to disable formating so that the copied link words will be only regular words? There is a button "remove formatting" but it doesn't do a thing in this case.

Comment: `CTRL + Shift + V` will paste without any kind of formatting, just like in a Word Document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this code in your functions.php

```
function tinymce_paste_as_text( $init ) {
      $init['paste_as_text'] = true;
      return $init;
    }

    add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_paste_as_text');
```

[For details please follow link :](https://wpseek.com/hook/tiny_mce_before_init/)

This will paste copied text in plain format